# How to set HOME env in batch file for program

Tags: batch, emacs

I'm trying to change the HOME environment variable to point to the current directory /HOME for Emacs so it uses the .emacs file from that directory.

This is what I have in my .bat file:

```
set HOME = .\HOME
bin\runemacs.exe %*
```

The problem is that it still uses the .\ folder, and not .\HOME

I'm not sure where to put this issue, because I don't know whether its the syntax of the batch file, or if it's Emacs.

Comment: Please add an OS tag, and explain what emacs variant are you talking about. This is definitely not vanilla emacs under Linux ...

Answer (score 0):

Windows CMD doesn't trim unquoted whitespace the way Unix shells usually do; you set an envvar whose name is "HOME " -- that is, H O M E SPACE -- to the value " .\HOME" . **Remove both spaces**, and also make sure there are no trailing spaces after the value (which can't be determined from your Q because they have no visual effect).

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out why it didn't work.
I've changed the code with qoutes, and changed directory name, but no result.

I went with a config folder instead of home, and cd into it, then set home, and run emacs from there, prepending a ..\

Code:

```
cd config
set HOME=.\
..\bin\runemacs.exe %*
```